# make columns editable by using if condition in w2ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

```
$('#grid').w2grid({ 
    name: 'grid',
    columns: [  
              { 
                  field: 'code', 
                  caption: 'Code', 
                  size: '120px', 
                  sortable: true, 
                  resizable: true, 
                  editable: { 
                      type: 'text' 
                  }
              }
```

I want to make it edit with if condition like if other fields are empty I don't want to make it editable. How I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two options:

Either set `record.w2ui.editable = false` for your specific record (this requires your data source to be dynamic and contain some sort of logic).

- or -

In w2ui 1.5, `grid.columns[i].editable` can also be a function instead of an object, so you can write your own check function that will determine if the cell will be editable.

Quote from the source files:

> col.editable can be a function which will be called with the same args as col.render()

Since the last one isn't well documented, I suggest you take a look at the implementation of `getCellEditable()` in the w2grid.js sources to get an idea how the two options I mentioned will interact.

Comment: But I have to decide depending on IF condtion.How I write if else here?